# keeping data in a raw mode while passing to re.match

Tags: python, string, text

In the source file, I have within the line the following data item (as is, len=11):

```
(?i:\'sa\')
```

When I pass it to a re.match, the matching (.groupdict()) value, written into a file, appears to be:

```
(?i:\sa\)
```

(len=9)

Question is, how to I preserve value `raw` (as in the following `b` example), between `re.match` and `file.write`

```
>>> a = '(?i:\'sa\')'
>>> b = r'(?i:\'sa\')'
>>> len(b)
11
>>> len(a)
9
>>> len(b)
11
>>> print b
(?i:\'sa\')
```

Note, since I am processing large and complex files provided by third party, I do not want nor can I change from `'a\'b'` to `"b'b"` but must keep things as they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably `string_escape` is what you need:

```
>>> s = raw_input()
(?i:\'sa\')
>>> s
"(?i:\\'sa\\')"
>>> len(s)
11
>>> s.decode('string_escape')
"(?i:'sa')"
>>> len(s.decode('string_escape'))
9
```